# How to exclude a jar-file from my Android library build target

Tags: android, jar, build, gradle, android-library

I am using Android Studio and have a several apps that rely on the same code. I moved shared code to a separate library in order to include it in my apps.

The library project (**MyLib**) that I created for this purpose requires a jar-file to compile, so I added it to project's libs directory.

My `build.gradle` of **MyLib** main module looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('./libs/external-java-lib.jar')
}
```

When I build the project, gradle generates a jar-file that contains `external-java-lib.jar`.

I want my Android application projects to provide "external-java-lib.jar", not the MyLib. Because in my apps I may use different versions of `external-java-lib.jar`.

**How do I configure Gradle to exclude `external-java-lib.jar` from the build of my library project?**

I couldn't find the answer to my question on the net, so I have a feeling that the thing I want is a piece of bad design. What else can I do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.

In my library project I added another empty **libraries** module and moved `external-java-lib.jar` to its `libs` folder.

In the `build.gradle` of the **main** module, I added dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries')     
}
```

My directory structure is now:

```
MyLibrary
├── build.gradle
├── gradle.properties
├── main
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│           ├── java ...
│           └── res  ...
├── libraries
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── libs
│   │   ├── external-lib-1.jar
│   │   └── external-lib-2.jar
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│           ├── java ...
│           └── res  ...
└── settings.gradle
```

After I build the library, the output aar-package had no `external-java-lib.jar` in it. So, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: Only solution which worked. However you can just keep the module separate and folder hierarchy doesn't matter that much

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using proguard then you simply use **provided** tag

```
dependencies {
    provided files('./libs/external-java-lib.jar')
}
```

Comment: this seems to just result in the same thing, ie. the jar getting included?

Comment: Doesn't work. The jar is still included in the build.

Answer (score 0):

i don not know about android studio but its easy in eclipse, in eclipse right click on the project-> properties->java build path there you have libraries and java build path. There you can exclude or include files.

Comment: It must be very simple, all I need is to add the jar to my class path and prevent it from being included into the release aar of the library. But my project is in Android studio and uses Gradle. I'd like to know how to do it in Gradle.

Comment: Well i don't know much of gradle, sorry but if you are able to do above steps and import again into gradle it will be win-win situation i guess :-)

Comment: I will try to do this as my backup plan. :) First, I want to wait if anyone can help me to configure gradle.